# Plot Graph in python using pandas and plotly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I was trying to plot graph using plotly in python. In my data frame i have two columns as Integer Value and EntryDate. On same date , there is possibility of having multiple value. I want my graph to plot all values in same line on same date.[Image is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nglLj.png)

```
import sys
import plotly
import pandas as pd
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = 'vscode'
import plotly.graph_objs as go
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
      "Server=SERVER;"
      "Database=DB;"
      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

SQL_Query=pd.read_sql_query("select EntryDate,Value from Measurement ;",conn)
df= pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query,columns=['Value','EntryDate'])
print (df)

trace1 = go.Scatter(
                x = df.EntryDate,
                y = df.Value,
                mode = "lines",                  
                marker = dict(color = 'rgba(16, 112, 2, 0.8)'),)                   


data = [trace1]
layout = go.Layout(title = 'PLOT',
          xaxis= dict(title= 'Entry Date',ticklen= 5,zeroline= False)
         )
fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)
fig.update_xaxes(rangeslider_visible= True)
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

Comment: Is the attached screenshot your desired output?

Comment: @vestland this is the output i am getting

Comment: OK, and how would you like to display it? Your provided figure does not seem to be very far from what you're describing your desired output to be...

Comment: @vestland thank you so much for your reply. I got the answered. I just fetch the date from database as datetime2 and plotly automatically detect it as date and plot it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I just fetch the date from database as datetime2 and plotly automatically detect it as date and plot it accordingly